# Select data (join?) from only one table using an id from another table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, that we'll call t1 and t2.  I want to select the data in t1 that has a certain ID that I can only find using a where clause in t2.  I don't want to select the data in t2 (many duplicate column names with different data) so how do I do that?

Comment: If you are only concerned with duplicate column names, then why dont you join the two tables and in you select clause just select from the first table?

Comment: There are too many columns...I wanted to use select *

Comment: Yes you can use `T1.*` in your select statement which would read all the values from T1 only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
select * from t1 where t1.Id in (select distinct Id from t2)
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for- added the where clause after t2 (where column = columnValue) and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to join the tables

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
 JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

You are joining them on a specific ID common between the 2 tables.

Comment: That selects the data from t2 which has the duplicate columns with unique data